# Best way to remove trailing character from a string (for example, trailing slashes)

Tags: nsis

i am looking for the best way to check for and strip trailing characters in a variable.

**For example, if last character is / then i want to remove it.**

Ex1: If $var is C:\mypath\ then i want output as only C:\mypath

Ex2: if $var is C:\mypath then output is C:\mypath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Function StripBackslash
Exch $0
Push $1
StrCpy $1 $0 "" -1
StrCmp $1 "\" 0 +2
StrCpy $0 $0 -1
Pop $1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd

Section

Push "c:\some\path\"
Call StripBackslash
Pop $0
DetailPrint |$0|
Push "c:\some\path"
Call StripBackslash
Pop $0
DetailPrint |$0|

;Alternative path validation:
Push $InstDir
StrCpy $InstDir "c:\some\path\"
StrCpy $0 $InstDir
Pop $InstDir
DetailPrint |$0|

SectionEnd
```