# Last character checking in a string

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to write the script in elegant way. i.e. write a piece of function or macro which will check a string for last character '\' and if found will add it to "sample" else it will add "\sample" and return it.

Anyone with any samples ?

Comment: Are you doing this to $InstDir on the directory page?

Comment: Your question is not really clear about how you want the final string to look. To me it sounds like you will end up with "sample\" or "sample\sample" but that is not really what you want is it?

Comment: Duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19683976/731081) asked Oct 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the last character of a string with `StrCpy $2 "$0" 1 -1`.

```
Function PathAppend
Exch $0
Exch 
Exch $1
Push $2
StrCpy $2 $1 1 -1
StrCmp $2 "\" +2 +1
    StrCpy $0 "\$0"
StrCpy $1 "$1$0"
Pop $2
Exch
Pop $0
Exch $1
FunctionEnd

Section
Push "c:\foo\bar"
Push "baz"
Call PathAppend
Pop $9
DetailPrint $9
SectionEnd
```

Note that the default directory set by `InstallDir` already has special handling if you want to append the application name to the directory.

Comment: I'm not concern about InstallDir as all are custom variables in my installer. Thanks for the quick answer. I will just make this function wrapped in a macro.